# JavaDocs with netbeans 7.3 not showing help incode

Tags: java, netbeans, jdk

I am running Ubuntu 12.10, I installed netbeans 7.3 full package and the javadocs are not found. I have tried to use the docs from online by going into Java Platform and adding the URL but then they will not show at all. Is this a netbeans problem or should I reinstall Java JDK and then reinstall netbeans? Or is there a quick fix so it will show me the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that it was a problem with the javaJDK that I installed from the ubuntu software center. All I had to do was uninstall it from the USC and then reinstall the java jdk from orcale and that fixed the problem.